# UIButton Differences between iOS 5.1 and 6.1

Tags: ios, uibutton, version

I placed 3 buttons into my view, set up background image and sometimes I need to disable one of them. I find out that they appear different in iOS 5.1 and 6.1. I like the 6.1 version. What should I do to make the design in 5.1 will be the same as in 6.1?

> 1) look at the white strip at the bottom of picture
>
> 2) third button is disabled and is quite lighter than in 6.1

[image: iOS5.1] <-- iOS5.1
[image: iOS6.1] <-- iOS6.1

PS: thank you for reputation points :)

Comment: +1 If someone else upvotes your question, you'll have enough rep to upload images. If you like, you can edit your question to add links, and someone else will usually find the images and add them for you.

Comment: You can add a link to the image and later include the image in the post when you have enough reps.

Comment: Have an upvote. Now post those images!

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots about the differences you are observing between ios 5.1 and 6.1?

Comment: You can always post the link to the images. Someone with enough rep will edit your question then

Answer (score 1):

The white artifact seems to be a default white rounded rect frame. Did you set button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there's a UI difference between two major versions of an OS, the right thing to do is to go with the flow and use the appearance that comes with each version. Having newer UI elements show up in an older version of the OS looks odd -- like your app doesn't quite fit in. Also, it's a lot of work to try to mimic the new look in the old OS.

Try to design your app so that it looks great with either variety of button, and your app will fit right in with the other apps on the user's device no matter what version they're using.

Comment: It's one way to solve the problem. But the white stripe at the bottom of button looks like some bug. What do you think?